# Consuming WCF service with .net api 2.0 / endpoint configuration failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

After add an Basic WCF server as Service Reference ,i try to run it and got error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: An endpoint
>   configuration section for contract 'AlineTest.ServicesSoap' could not
>   be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that
>   contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint
>   configuration section by name. at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupChannel(ContextInformation
>   configurationContext, String configurationName, ContractDescription
>   contract, EndpointAddress address, Boolean wildcard, Boolean
>   useChannelElementKind, ServiceEndpoint& serviceEndpoint) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String
>   configurationName, EndpointAddress address) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String
>   endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1
>   endpointTrait) at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef() at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor() at
>   ComboProjectReference.AlineTest.ServicesSoapClient..ctor() in
>   c:\users\nguyen ba nguyen\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\ComboProjectReference\ComboProjectReference\Connected
>   Services\AlineTest\Reference.cs:line 2898 at
>   ComboProjectReference.Controllers.ValuesController.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in c:\users\nguyen ba nguyen\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\ComboProjectReference\ComboProjectReference\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line
>   28

my code for consuming WCF :

> ```
>   try
>         {
>             ServicesSoapClient client = new ServicesSoapClient();
>             Task<CustomerAccountInfo[]> GetAccount = client.GetAccountAsync(User, Password, DemoAccount);
>             CustomerAccountInfo[] AccountInfor = await GetAccount;
>             foreach(CustomerAccountInfo a in AccountInfor)
>             {
>                 AccountView.Add(a);
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             AccountView.Error = ex.ToString();
>             return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
>         }
> ```

It seem like i need to config/ add endpoint configuration at the line

> ServicesSoapClient client = new ServicesSoapClient();

but i can't find where the connected services save the endpoint configuration .
[WCF reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZmcI.png)

So any help to config endpoint is welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

Find out the string endpointConfigurationName listed on web.config file. My string endpointConfigurationName in web.config is look like

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://***" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesSoap" contract="AlineTest.ServicesSoap" name="ServicesSoap" />
      <endpoint address="https://***" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesSoap12" contract="AlineTest.ServicesSoap" name="ServicesSoap12" />
      <endpoint address="https://***" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SubscriberManagementSoap" contract="Mytv.SubscriberManagementSoap" name="SubscriberManagementSoap" />
      <endpoint address="https://***" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SubscriberManagementSoap12" contract="Mytv.SubscriberManagementSoap" name="SubscriberManagementSoap12" />
    </client>
```

so i added string "ServicesSoap" to my  ServicesSoapClient client = new ServicesSoapClient(); and it work

```
  try
        {
            ServicesSoapClient client = new ServicesSoapClient("ServicesSoap");
            Task<CustomerAccountInfo[]> GetAccount = client.GetAccountAsync(User, Password, DemoAccount);
            CustomerAccountInfo[] AccountInfor = await GetAccount;
            foreach(CustomerAccountInfo a in AccountInfor)
            {
                AccountView.Add(a);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AccountView.Error = ex.ToString();
            return BadRequest(ex.ToString());
        }
```